# Configure WCF service server side to accept Mtom

Tags: c#, .net, web-services, wcf, soap

I'm pretty new to web services and I'm trying to configure my WCF service to pull files from another service using the Visual WCF service template.

I've managed to pull everything except for the content data. I've searched and found that I have to use Mtom instead of Text for message encoding. Problem is i'm not sure how to configure my web service to use MessageEncoding = Mtom. I've fiddled with the web.config file but i can't seem to configure it properly.

This is my service interface

```
 [ServiceContract]
public interface IService
{

    [OperationContract]
    string test(changeData data);
    [OperationContract]
    RetrieveChangeListResponse GetChangeList();
    [OperationContract]
    RetrieveChangeTaskListResponse GetTaskList();
    [OperationContract]
    RetrieveInteractionAttachmentResponse GetFile(string id);

    // TODO: Add your service operations here
}
```

This is my web.config

```
<system.serviceModel>
<bindings>
  <basicHttpBinding>
    <binding name="basicHttp" allowCookies="true"
             maxReceivedMessageSize="20000000"
             maxBufferSize="20000000"
             maxBufferPoolSize="20000000"
             messageEncoding ="Mtom">
      <readerQuotas maxDepth="32"
           maxArrayLength="200000000"
           maxStringContentLength="200000000"/>
    </binding>
  </basicHttpBinding>
</bindings>
<services>
  <service name="IService"
           behaviorConfiguration="ServiceWithMetadata">
    <endpoint name="BasicHttpBinding_IService"
              binding="basicHttpBinding"
              bindingConfiguration="basicHttp"
              contract="IService" />
  </service>
</services>
<behaviors>
  <serviceBehaviors>
    <behavior name="ServiceWithMetadata">
      <serviceMetadata httpGetEnabled="true" />
      <serviceDebug includeExceptionDetailInFaults="false" />
    </behavior>
  </serviceBehaviors>
</behaviors>
<protocolMapping>
  <add binding="basicHttpsBinding" scheme="https"/>
</protocolMapping>
<serviceHostingEnvironment aspNetCompatibilityEnabled="true" multipleSiteBindingsEnabled="true"/>
```

Currently if use this setup I get this error:

> Error: Cannot obtain Metadata from localhost:50282/Service.svc If this is a Windows (R) Communication Foundation service to which you have access, please check that you have enabled metadata publishing at the specified address.  For help enabling metadata publishing, please refer to the MSDN documentation at     URI: localhost:50282/Service.svc    Metadata contains a reference that cannot be resolved: 'localhost:50282/Service.svc'.    Content Type application/soap+xml; charset=utf-8 was not supported by service localhost:50282/Service.svc.  The client and service bindings may be mismatched.    The remote server returned an error: (415) Cannot process the message because the content type 'application/soap+xml; charset=utf-8' was not the expected type 'text/xml; charset=utf-8'..HTTP GET Error    URI: localhost:50282/Service.svc    The HTML document does not contain Web service discovery information.

If I remove these settings I get a type mismatch like this:

> Client found response content type of 'multipart/related; type="text/xml"; boundary="----=_Part_0_30957184.1421681490926"', but expected 'text/xml'.

I understand there is a config for the WcfTestClient and a config for the actual service, but I don't understand how to properly configure my server side to properly accept Mtom encoding.

Could someone explain how to properly configure the server side binding ? I use **BasicHttpBinding**, but would also like to use **wshHttpBinding** for soap 1.2 functionality.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem was in the the authentification method used, i was using annonymous instead of basic. 
Also you can't have method return types that are proxy data types. If you have such a method you will get an error about class derivation.